# Is it possible to attach package environments as parents of a specific environment, not the global environment, in R?

Tags: r, package, parent, environment, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to create a toy R REPL written in R ([here's](https://github.com/dhersz/replr/blob/master/R/replr.R) the source code). Ideally I'd like the REPL to run in an R terminal itself, but neither to interfere nor to depend on anything that has already been evaluated at the global environment. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to do come up with a solution to this problem yet. One of the main challenges I'm facing refers to how package environments are attached.

According to [Hadley's Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#search-path), packages attached by `library()` and `require()` become parents of the global environment. This implies, however, that if I attach a package inside my toy REPL it will become the parent of the global environment even I'm not running it on the global environment.

For example (please note that the `R>` prompt is the "normal" R terminal, and that `>>>>` is my REPL's "terminal"):

```r
R> search()
#  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
#  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
#  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
# [10] "package:base"     
R> replr::replr(env = new.env()) # new.env() defaults to having global environment as a parent
>>>> library(gtfsio)
>>>> rlang::env_parents(last = emptyenv())
#  [[1]] $ <env: global>
#  [[2]] $ <env: package:gtfsio>
#  [[3]] $ <env: tools:rstudio>
#  [[4]] $ <env: package:stats>
#  [[5]] $ <env: package:graphics>
#  [[6]] $ <env: package:grDevices>
#  [[7]] $ <env: package:utils>
#  [[8]] $ <env: package:datasets>
#  [[9]] $ <env: package:methods>
# [[10]] $ <env: Autoloads>
# [[11]] $ <env: package:base>
# [[12]] $ <env: empty>
>>>> import_gtfs()
# Error: argument "path" is missing, with no default
>>>> q()
R> search()
#  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:gtfsio"    "tools:rstudio"    
#  [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
#  [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
# [10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

We can see that I could use the `gtfsio`' `import_gtfs()` function (the `path` is missing, but you get the point), but the package was also attached to the "main" R terminal. If I try to use another environment as the parent to my new env, I won't even have access to the package's functions, because it won't be able to find them, since the package environment becomes the parent of the global environment, and not of my new environment:

```r
Restarting R session...

R> search()
#  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
#  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
#  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
# [10] "package:base" 
R> replr::replr(env = new.env(parent = baseenv()))
>>>> library(gtfsio)
>>>> rlang::env_parents()
# [[1]] $ <env: package:base>
# [[2]] $ <env: empty>
>>>> import_gtfs()
# Error: could not find function "import_gtfs"
>>>> q()
R> search()
#  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:gtfsio"    "tools:rstudio"    
#  [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
#  [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
# [10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

So, is there any way of attaching package environments as parents of a custom environment, instead of the global environment? If there's not, is there any way to workaround this issue?

Cheers!

---

**Edit:**

Sorry, I should have given more details on how the REPL works.

Basically, I just read the user input using `readline()`, parse it as an expression and evaluate it in the specified environment. The code below should work for a simple demonstration:

```r
simple_repl <- function(env = new.env()) {
    
  while (TRUE) {
    
    input <- readline(">>>> ")
    
    if (input == "q()") break
    
    expr <- parse(text = input)
    
    result <- withVisible(
      eval(expr, envir = env)
    )
      
    if (result$visible)
      print(result$value)
      
  }
    
}
```

The code I linked above to my GitHub is a bit more complex to handle some conditions, but still, this is the basic idea.

A `library()` call would then be evaluated as `eval(expression(library(gtfsio)), envir = env)`.

Comment: It's hard to test things because we can't run your REPL. Is it possible to translate this into functions we can easily test with?

Comment: You'll have effects going both ways here—things done outside will affect stuff happening inside, and vice versa. The usual approach to avoid this is [to run in a separate process](https://github.com/r-lib/callr/blob/master/R/run.R) so you get a new, isolated instance of R every time.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, you're definitely right. I have added a simple REPL to test with to the question.

Comment: @alistaire Yeah, I know there are effects going both ways, and probably running a separate process is a neat way to protect against such effects, but I'd like to keep to the same process, if possible. Thanks for directing to callr anyway, I'll check the code to see if it brings some good ideas.

Comment: `library()` and company have a `pos` param to allow you to attach packages/namespaces in different orders, but afaik there's only one search path and one set of loaded namespaces within an R session. Packages are not just environments; there's more going on there. You could try to override and reproduce the package infra or clean up on exit, but both of those routes are fraught. Also keep an eye on things like env vars and options, which will face similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one search path so there's no way to properly attach to another one.

You can still have a chain of parent environments though, we might redefine `library` in your `repl_env` to set up this chain

```
repl_env <- new.env()
with(repl_env, library <- function(package) {
  # fetch repl_env from the inside
  repl_env    <- parent.env(environment())
  # and its parent (.GlobalEnv the first time)
  parent_env <- parent.env(repl_env)
  # create a new env for our package and fill it
  pkg_env <- new.env()
  package <- deparse1(substitute(package))
  object_nms <- getNamespaceExports(package)
  objects    <- mget(object_nms, envir = asNamespace(package))
  list2env(objects, pkg_env)
  # stitch it above repl_env and below repl_env's parent
  parent.env(pkg_env) <- parent_env
  parent.env(repl_env) <- pkg_env
  # base::library returns the search path invisibly but here it woudn't make
  # sense so we just return NULL
  invisible(NULL)
})

simple_repl(repl_env)
>>>> x <- "hello"
>>>> y <- "world"
>>>> library(glue)
>>>> glue("{x} {y}")
#> hello world
>>>> 

# the {glue} package is not on the search path  
search()
#> [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
#> [5] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
#> [9] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Use `repl_env <- new.env(parent = parent.env(.GlobalEnv))` as your first line if you don't want to have access to the global environment's objects.

It will never be 100% robust however, it was a fun exercise but think carefully before doing something serious with this.

Comment: That's a great workaround! I imagined I'd have to write a custom `library()`, but I wouldn't know how to do so. I'll try studying your code in more details in the next few days, since there's a lot of stuff going on over there that I don't really know how it works :P And don't worry, I don't really plan on doing anything serious with this, it's just a toy.